# Can Jpa transaction and jdbc transaction use same datasource

Tags: jpa, datasource, spring-jdbc

I have a code which uses Hibernate Jpa transaction and an independent scheduler is written which uses jdbctransaction . My application context xml has both org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager and org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager beans. Can both the transaction managers use same datasource defined in xml. Or do I need to create a new datasource bean for jdbc transaction